Best Robotics platform for development and demos
I'm searching to buy two robotics platforms to develop algorithms and make demos.
I prefer not to take robotics arms.
The robots should move outdoors and indoors, and they are sold by companies that can support them if there is an HW issue.
One last point is that the integration should be easy.
I have already seen Clearpath, Unitree, Pal, and Robotnik.
Any more suggestions?

Welcome to Robotics Tzik, but I'm afraid that shopping questions really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the Robotics question checklist for details of how to write a good question.

There are still a lot of criteria you haven't discussed - "move" has wheels? Does outdoor mean some degree of water protection or something else? You mention integration, but integration of what? Does it need to be wifi or Bluetooth or USB? Do you need ports for other equipment like cameras or something else? Are you okay with kits/DIY or do you want a complete/turn-key product? How big, how fast, what price range, etc. Once you start making decisions you'll narrow it down to something specific to you, which is why these questions are off-topic - it's not helpful for future visitors.
